# Find lim$_{n \rightarrow \infty}$ $\int_0^a f(nx)\; dx$

Tags: real-analysis

Let *f* be continuous on [0,+$\infty$), where lim$_{n \rightarrow \infty}$ *f (x)* exists in $\bar{\mathbb{R}}$ and a > 0. Find:

lim$_{n \rightarrow \infty}$ $\int_0^a \;f (nx)\; dx$

I have tried to start with change change of variables and then proceed with the MVT after applying the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. However, I get stuck with an expression containing f(c), where c can be anything between 0 and $+\infty$. Could someone help me with this one?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: if $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(x)$ is a finite number $L$, 
for any $\epsilon > 0$ there is $M$ such that $L-\epsilon < f(x) < L + \epsilon$ for $x > M$.  What does that say about $\int_{M/n}^a f(nx)\; dx$?
You'll still have to deal with $\int_0^{M/n} f(nx)\; dx$, which you can do because $f$ is bounded on $[0,M]$.

If $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(x) = +\infty$ or $-\infty$, do something similar with $f(x) > N$ or $f(x) < -N$.

Answer (score 1):

Another hint: For any $t>0,$

$$\int_0^a f(tx)\,dx = \frac{\int_0^{at} f(y)\,dy }{t}.$$

We want the limit of this as $t\to \infty.$ Use L'Hopital together with the FTC.